# TFS 2010 Debugging not stopping at Breakpoints

Tags: debugging, build

I am trying to debug a custom Build Template by attaching to the TFSBuildServiceHost.exe and then Queuing the build.  No breakpoints are being hit so I am looking for ideas on what else to configure.

I am using this article as a reference:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/baruchf/archive/2009/07/02/debugging-team-build-now-you-can.aspx

Comment: I actually got this to work some time ago and forgot about this post.  The issue involved general remote debugging with Visual Studio and properly sharing out debug symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your Output window while you are attached to TFSBuildServiceHost.exe. Do you have a line like this

> Instrumentation for debugger fails.  Reason: Could not find file 'c:\blah\blah\blah\BuildProcessTemplates\MyBuildTemplate.xaml'..'TFSBuildServiceHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Workflow'

The build template file records the path to itself inside the file. Open up your build process template file in a text editor. Look for a `XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName` attribute within. If the value of that attribute doesn't match the actual file location of the xaml file you had open when you were setting breakpoints, the debugger will not be able to hit those breakpoints.